# image processing using neural networks from scratch

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I am trying to use neural networks with back propagation for image recognition of numbers from 0-9.
It uses back propagation and CNN's to do this but i can't seem to get it working right now. I feel like it is overfitting to a data image but then completlely changes when going onto the next test image. Is this just a problem of not enough test data or is there a major problem in my code

```
from skimage import io,img_as_float,transform
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from random import randint, random, uniform
import numpy as np
import sys


class Data:
    data_dict = {}

    def __init__(self, limit,number_of_inputs):
        self.limit = limit

    """creates data but beware that the limit may not be the same as the size of the dictionary"""

    def create_data(self):
        
        for i in range(1,10):
            for j in range(0,10):
                image = io.imread(f"images/numbers/{j}.{i}.png")
                image = transform.resize(image, (8, 8), anti_aliasing=True)
                label = i
                self.data_dict[(i, j)]= label

""" you compare the error with every test in the data set and find weights that minimise the error"""

class Neural:
    def __init__(self, data,num_of_nodes,num_of_inputs):

        self.num_of_nodes = num_of_nodes
        self.num_of_inputs = num_of_inputs
         
        self.inputs = []
        
        for i in range(num_of_inputs):
            self.inputs.append(0)
  
        self.first_layer_weights = []
        for i in range (num_of_nodes * num_of_inputs):
            self.first_layer_weights.append(uniform(-1, 1))
            
        self.second_layer_weights = []
        for i in range (num_of_nodes):
          self.second_layer_weights.append(uniform(-1, 1))
          
        self.data = data

    def relu(self, number):
        return max(0, number)

    def sigmoid(self, number):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-number))

    """weighted summation with activation function to compute output """

    def imageToArray(self,my_image):
        filters = np.array([[-1,-1,1,0,1,-1,0,1,1],[1,0,0,1,-1,-1,1,0,-1],[0,1,1,0,1,0,1,-1,1]])
        currentArray = []  
        for row in range(8-2):
            rowArray=[]
            for pixel in range(8-2): #i resized everything to 8 by 8 so can assume there are 8 pixels right now
                try:
                    totalPixelValue = 0

                    pixelArray = np.array([])
                    for color in range(0,3):
                        for rowValue in range(3):
                            for columnValue in range(3):
                                pixelArray = np.append(pixelArray, my_image[row+rowValue][pixel+columnValue][color])
                        
                        totalPixelValue+=np.sum(pixelArray * filters[color]) 
                        pixelArray = np.array([])
                    rowArray.append(totalPixelValue)
                    
                except Exception as e:
                    print("An error occurred:", e)
            if rowArray != []:
                currentArray.append(rowArray)
        #pooling layer using max pooling
        finalArray = []
        for row in range(0,len(currentArray),2):
            for column in range(0,len(currentArray[row]),2):
                finalArray.append(max(currentArray[row][column],currentArray[row+1][column],currentArray[row][column+1],currentArray[row+1][column+1]))

        return finalArray

    def compute_output(self,inputs):
        
       # num1, num2 = num1 / 100, num2 / 100
        inputs = list(inputs)
        print(inputs)
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            inputs[i] /= 100
        return_value = 0
        for i in range(self.num_of_nodes):
            temp_var = 0
            count = 0
            for j in inputs:
               # return_value+= self.sigmoid((num1 *  self.first_layer_weights[2 * i]) + (num2 *  self.first_layer_weights[2 * i + 1])) * self.second_layer_weights[i]
               temp_var+= j *  self.first_layer_weights[self.num_of_inputs * i + count]
               count+=1
            return_value += self.sigmoid(temp_var) * self.second_layer_weights[i]    
            
        return 100 * return_value

    #softmax algorithm to normalize the outputs into probabilities

    """mean swaured error error between the actual output with the output generated by the algorithm """

    def compare_ouput(self, data):
        """actually,better to find error between all tests. add all the errors up"""
        error = 0
        for key in data.data_dict:
            error += abs(data.data_dict[key] - self.compute_output(key)) ** 2
        return error / len(data.data_dict)

    # return abs(actual - self.compute_output(num1,num2))

    """TODO function that changes the weight depending on the errors using gradient descent"""
    """first make it random"""
    """next perhaps change weights for each test and average out the adjustments for each weight"""

    def random_back_propagation(self):
        error = sys.maxsize
        while error > 100 :
            for (index,weight) in enumerate(self.first_layer_weights):
                self.first_layer_weights[index] = uniform(0,1)
                
            for (index,weight) in enumerate(self.second_layer_weights):
               self.second_layer_weights[index] = uniform(0,1)
                
            error = self.compare_ouput(self.data)
            print(error)
       # print(self.compute_output([140, 15]))

        """learning rate is the amount the weights are updated during training"""

    def back_propagation(self, learning_rate):
        for epoch in range(500):
            if epoch%10 == 0:
                epoch/=1.1
            errors = []
            for key in self.data.data_dict:

                self.inputs = list(self.imageToArray(f"images/numbers/{key[0]}.{key[1]}.png"))
                target = self.data.data_dict[key]

                # Rescaling everything
                for i in range(len(self.inputs)):
                    self.inputs[i] /= 100
                target = target / 100
                
                hidden_layer_outputs=[]

                for i in range(self.num_of_nodes):
                    temp_var = 0
                    count = 0
                    for j in self.inputs:
                       temp_var+= j *  self.first_layer_weights[self.num_of_inputs  * i + count]
                       count+=1
                    hidden_layer_outputs.append(self.sigmoid(temp_var)  )   
                                            
                output = 0
                for i in range(self.num_of_nodes):
                    output+=  ( hidden_layer_outputs[i] * self.second_layer_weights[i])           

                # loss
                error = (target - output) ** 2
                # check if you are happpy with the error

                # derivative of error with respect to output
                # d(error)/d(output) = -2 * (target - output)

                # derivative of error with respect to x1
                # d(error)/d(x1) = d(error)/d(output) * d(output)/d(x1)
                #                                                      /-> hidden_layer1_output
                # d(error)/d(x1) = d(error)/d(output) * ( d(output)/d(hl1) * d(hl1)/d(x1) )

                #   derivative of output with respect to hl1
                #   d(output)/d(hl1) = z1

                #   derivative of hl1 with respect to x1
                #   d(hl1)/d(x1) = hidden_layer1_output * (1 - hidden_layer1_output) * num1

                # d(error)/d(x1) = -2 * (target - output) * z1 * hidden_layer1_output * (1 - hidden_layer1_output) * num1
         
                for i in range(self.num_of_nodes):
                    temp_var = 0
                    count = 0
                    for j in self.inputs:
                        self.first_layer_weights[self.num_of_inputs *i + count]  -= learning_rate * -2 * (target - output) * self.second_layer_weights[i] * hidden_layer_outputs[i] * (1 - hidden_layer_outputs[i]) * j
                        count+=1                             
                           
                # derivative of error with respect to z1
                # d(error)/d(z1) = d(error)/d(output) * d(output)/d(z1)

                #   derivative of output with respect to z1
                #   d(output)/d(z1) = hidden_layer1_output

                # d(error)/d(z1) = -2(target - output) * hidden_layer1_output
                
                for i in range(self.num_of_nodes):
                    self.second_layer_weights[i] -= learning_rate * -2 * (target - output) * hidden_layer_outputs[i]
                errors.append(error)
                print(target , output)
            print(f"Mean error: {np.mean(errors)}")

number_of_inputs = 10

data = Data(4000,number_of_inputs)
data.create_data()

neural = Neural(data,3,90)
neural.back_propagation(0.0095)

my_image = io.imread("images/numbers/2.1.png")

image = io.imread('images/numbers/2.1.png')
image = transform.resize(image, (8, 8), anti_aliasing=True)
```

last line of code is `print(f"image 2 {neural.compute_output(neural.imageToArray( image))}")` but for some reason doesnt allow for me to add

The test images look like this :
[image]

I have tried changing the number of nodes in the neural network and changing the learning factor but perhaps i need to change the filters for it? There is only one output because i want it to just give the number result instead of the probability of it being each number.